# Couldn't get GridView's ItemCounts in ScrollView

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I have a layout which has some some TextViews and ImageView on the top of the screen and a `GridView`. You know `GridView` has own scroll and GridView's `ScrollListener` says me `firstVisibleItem`, `visibleItemCount` and `totalItemCount`.

My problem is that when I want to scroll my layout from the top, I have to put my all layout into ScrollView so my GridView(`ExpandableHeightGridView`) does not get the correct itemcounts. If I dont put a `ScrollView`, I can't scroll from the top.

How to deal with this problem? How can I scroll my all layout from the top.

Remember, my major problem is getting wrong itemcounts. I want to load more items when scroll reachs at the bottom so I have to read itemcounts.
Thank you to all. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have two scrolling containers one in the other. I'd expect the `GridView` to misbehave when it's inside a `ScrollView`.

The cleanest solution to your problem would be to use the concept of ListView's `addHeaderView()`. As `GridView` doesn't support headers though, you'll have to use another Google's class, namely **`HeaderGridView`**: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I am not aware of this and probably this will solve my problem. I will check this and mark your answer accepted :)